# pathfinder problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I have created a very complex map in Illustrator. I am trying to cut out smaller areas of the map for use in other SketchUp. Neither pathfinder nor Divide Below gives me predicted results. 
I turn off layers I don't need, then flatten the whole thing which gets rid of alot of stuff. The resulting file is not that complicated. I then draw a square (1-point stroke, no fill). I want to keep everything inside the square get rid of everything outside. When I perform Pathfinder > Divide I get a big mess that makes no sense. Divide Below doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Hi there! Can you upload some screenshots?

Comment: hey @Yisela I got Divide to work, sort of, but can't put a screenshot in comments

Comment: you can [edit] you question to incorporate screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Pathfinder doesn't understand strokes very well.

Set your rectangle to a solid fill and no stroke.

Then select the rectangle and artwork and click the **Crop** button on the `Pathfinder Panel`.

Comment: Thanks, I did get Divide below to work when I made the rectangle solid. And you are right, not all the strokes were properly cut. I had to do that by hand. But mostly it worked ok.

Comment: You can always outline the strokes so everything is a filled shape.

Comment: Agree with plainclothes, some pathfinders remove the stroke.
Also, I don't know a thing about SketchUp, but you could try to make a clipping mask with the rectangle on top of the mask, go to Objects > Clipping Mask > Create. It will just hide the map, don't know if it helps.

Comment: For what its worth strokes cannot be cut because it wouldn't work out anyway as the strike would lose the info on how it was cut